# mousewheel Event on dynamically added elelement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Long story short, I am trying to bind a 'mousewheel' event to a div that has a scrollbar on it.

My code works when I use it outside of the plugin I created, but when I try turn it into a plugin, It does nothing. I tried changing 'mousewheel' to click and see if that works and it does so it seems to be just the 'mousewheel' event that is not being picked up....

any clues?

```
scroller = "<div class='scale_window'>";

for (var i = options.numFrom; i <= options.numTo; i++) {
    scroller += "<div>" + i + "</div>";
}

scroller += "</div>";

$(this).html(scroller);
$('.scale_window', this).on('mousewheel', function (e) {
    console.log("hmm");
});
```

I want to try and do this with out using the "jquery.mousewheel" plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).on('mousewheel','.scale_window', function (e) {
    console.log("hmm");
});
```